# Number validation using a regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

In a web application, while validating the textbox using a regular expression, I have written the expression to validate only digits not starting with zero, with 3 digits after the decimal points. But if I type only a single digit, it's giving me a message. Can you help me with the regular expression? I'm looking for an expression which would not accept a leading digit of zero and accept only 3 decimals like 12.336, 1.254, 10.20, etc.

Comment: Do you want exactly 3 decimal or 0 to 3? In the example you say `10.20` wich is 2 decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you want:

This will match numbers not begining with 0 and having exactly 3 decimal

```
^[1-9]\d*\.\d{3}$
```

This will match numbers not begining with 0 and having 1 to 3 decimal or none.

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
[1-9]\d*\.?\d{0,3}
```

If you wish to ignore whitespace, just add \s*:

```
\s*[1-9]\d*\.?\d{0,3}\s*
```

BTW, there are ton of visual tools for writing regular expressions – I recommend Expresso.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
^[1-9]\d*.?\d{0,3}$
```

Note this will also fail if there are spaces at either end of the string, remove the `^` at the start and the `$` at the end if this is not as desired.

Comment: @Tim - So it did!  I've modified my answer